# Generic typing for some utility functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, javascript-objects

I have some utility functions that I want to add generic types to in typescript but can't figure out how to do it.

*(These are based on the functionality of ramda but I don't want to use ramda in this project.)*

**pick :**

```js
function pick(keys, object) {
  const result = Object.assign(
    {},
    ...keys.map(k => (k in object ? { [k]: object[k] } : {}))
  );
  return result;
}
```

**reject :**

```js
function reject(keys, object) {
  const result = Object.assign(
    {},
    ...Object.keys(object)
      .filter(k => !keys.includes(k))
      .map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] }))
  );
  return result;
}
}
```

... I'd like to use them like this and have typescript work out the resultant type :

```js
type Item = {title: string, description: string}

const test: { [key: string]: Item } = {
  a: { title: 'TitleA', description: 'DescriptionA' },
  b: { title: 'TitleB', description: 'DescriptionB' },
  c: { title: 'TitleC', description: 'DescriptionC' },
  d: { title: 'TitleD', description: 'DescriptionD' }
};

const test1 = pick(['a', 'c'], test) // {a: { title: 'TitleA', description: 'DescriptionA' }, c: { title: 'TitleC', description: 'DescriptionC' }}
const test2 = reject(['a', 'c'], test) // {b: { title: 'TitleB', description: 'DescriptionB' },d: { title: 'TitleD', description: 'DescriptionD' }}
```

> Does anyone have a suggestion of how to add generic typing to these `pick` and `reject` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two generic type parameters, one for the object itself and one for the picked keys. Then you can add a type boundary to the keys to be a subset of the object keys. The return type is then a mapped type of the keys looked up on the object:

```
 function pick<O, K extends keyof O>(keys: K[], object: O): { [T in K]: O[T] }
```

The `reject` function can be typed similarily:

```
 function reject<O, K extends keyof O>(keys: K[], object: O): { [T in keyof O]: T extends K ? undefined : O[T] }
```

Comment: [In action](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxhA1gHgPIBpEDSiApgB5TFgAmAzousQJ5zCLYB8AFA4zQFyEA2gF18cAEYArYtAHYAlAIDeiQQBVEMJDxZthAjWQrU6RAPxt1wxAPBViwLcSqIAvoiUAoRIggIaUIgATsQ0IAA2gQC8bFIyUAB0AIY0NDAA5mCc3j4errg5PgnFPDQJALZJyNyIUeyINVqIEtLQiBYqguj6zXHQXdbuyq7y8jnyANw5IVAgQUghYZFTrp6eqBicggBESdv42+L7iNvE26IeiEkCAEz44gIAzPgQAgAsI55AA)

Comment: Wow, thanks. This is some kind of magic.. I'm going to try and understand how this works. However there is one ts error on the reject function now : **`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'. 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.`**. Related to the `keys.includes()` part.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need a typecast there.

Comment: @juliusbangert quick explanation of pick: O is the type of the object you're picking from. K extends the subset of the keys of O. T is a member of K (i.e. one of the keys of the object) mapped to O[T] (the value of the object at that key). Reject uses the same setup.